# Pass Dynamic ID to Jquery on Document Ready Function

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Sorry to ask this question as I cant figure out whats wrong with my code.

This is my data table. I added an action Edit and Delete.
[image]

When I clicked the Edit link, it will trigger a modal pop-up like this one.
[image]

What I want is when I click on the input field "Date", I am expecting the datetime picker is triggered.

Here is my current code:

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal-body">
<label>Date:</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class='input-group date'>
        <input type='text' class="form-control datepicker" id="ot_date_<?php echo $edit_id; ?>" name="ot_date_edit" placeholder="Enter OT Date" required=""/>
        <span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span> </span>
    </div>
</div>

<label>OT Time-in:</label>
    <div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group date">
        <input type='text' class="form-control datepicker"  id="ot_timein_edit" name="ot_timein_edit" placeholder="Enter OT Time-in" required=""/>
        <span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> </span>
    </div>
</div>

<label>OT Time-out:</label>
<div class="form-group">
    <div class="input-group date">
        <input type='text' class="form-control datepicker" id="ot_timeout_edit" name="ot_timeout_edit" placeholder="Enter OT Time-out" required="" />
        <span class="input-group-addon"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-time"></span> </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

**JSS:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("input").click(function (e) {        
        var getthevalue = $(this).attr('id');
        var Edit_ID = "#" + getthevalue ;
        $(Edit_ID).datetimepicker({
            format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
        }); 
    });

});
```

Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to 'extract' the ID from correct input, you can access the clicked input by `$(this)`

**Edit** - replaced `$(this)` with `event.target`, added a `if` condition for date / time picker

**Edit 2** - replaced `.click(function(event){});` with `.focus(function(event){});`

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery(".datepicker").focus(function (event) {        
        var id = event.target.id;
        if(id == 'ot_timein_edit' || id == 'ot_timeout_edit'){
            //display timepicker for time by accessing the element with e.target
        } else {
            //Show date picker 
            $(event.target).datetimepicker({
                format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
            }); 
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: this won't work well inside a click handler on the same element

Comment: So you recommend to use `event` and access the clicked input by `event.target` ?

Comment: Hi @RamisWachtler, 
Thanks a lot for your reply. Actually, I just created another class for the "Time-in" and "Time-Out" and its ok now. The time selection is now shown. But my issue is, when you load the modal pop-up, on the FIRST time you click that input, the calendar is not shown. You need to go to another input field and go back again then the calendar is shown. I suspect, is it because click event dont load immediately the datetimepicker plugin? Unlike if I used like this one:  
$('#ot_date').datetimepicker({
format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
});

the calendar is shown at the first hit.

Comment: Hm, it's maybe because `.click()` isn't really a suitable for this. Try `.focus(function(event){});`

Comment: Or delete focus and use it like you said in your last sentence, just for each input field. Like `$('#ot_date').datetimepicker({ format: 'MM/DD/YYYY' });` , `$('#ot_time_in').datetimepicker({ format: 'HH:mm' });` and `$('#ot_time_out').datetimepicker({ format: 'HH:mm' });` ,